# The set $S=\{m^2+dn^2|m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$, $\frac qp=r -$ integer. Prove that $r \in S$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

> Let $d$ integer number and the set $S=\{m^2+dn^2|m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$. Let $p,q \in S$ such that $p -$ prime and $\frac qp=r -$ integer. Prove that $r \in S$.

I do not know how it can help, but
$$(x^2+dy^2)(u^2+dv^2)=(xu\pm dyv)^2+d(xv \mp yu)^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for integer $m,$ including negative. It even works if $m = -w^2,$ although that case many of the variables are determined by the necessity of writing a prime as $1 \cdot p.$ Note that Dickson discusses all possible ways of solving $x^2 + m y^2 = z w$ on page 91 of his Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. In a separate chapter, Dickson covers indefinite forms by the methods of Lagrange, which is the right way to do Pell's equation.

$$  p = r^2 + m s^2, $$
so
$$ p - r^2 = m s^2. $$
$$  np = x^2 + m y^2. $$ 
$$  s^2 np = s^2 x^2 + m s^2 y^2 = s^2 x^2 + (p-r^2) y^2 = s^2 x^2 - r^2 y^2 + p y^2  $$
$$  s^2 np - p y^2 = s^2 x^2 - r^2 y^2  $$
We see that
$$ p | (s^2 x^2 - r^2 y^2) = (sx+ry)(sx-ry). $$
We are going to choose $\pm r$ so that $ p | (sx-ry).$ Then
$$ sx-ry = pt, \; \; \; sx + ry = pt + 2ry.  $$
$$ (s^2 x^2 - r^2 y^2)= p^2 t^2 + 2prty $$
$$  ( s^2 np - p y^2) = p^2 t^2 + 2 prty  $$
Here we can divide out $p$
$$  ( s^2 n -  y^2) = p t^2 + 2 rty  $$
$$ s^2 n = y^2 + 2 r y t + p t^2  $$
$$ s^2 n = (y^2 + 2 r y t + r^2 t^2) + (p t^2 - r^2 t^2)  $$
$$ s^2 n = (y + rt)^2 + (p  - r^2) t^2  $$
$$ s^2 n = (y + rt)^2 + m s^2 t^2  $$
Now we have
 $$   s^2 | (y + rt)^2.  $$
By unique factorization,
$$ s | (y+rt).  $$
Indeed, we take
$$ y + rt = su. $$ Then $ s^2 n = (y + rt)^2 + m s^2 t^2  $ becomes
$$ s^2 n = s^2 u^2 + m s^2 t^2  $$
$$  n =  u^2 + m  t^2  $$

[image]